# How to login to website or access existing cookie to use file_get_contents

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

I would like to use file_get_contents to pull some information from [investors.com](http://www.investors.com/NewsAndAnalysis/Article.aspx?sec=Investing&col=BigPicture).  Is there a way to use my existing session cookie or pass login information to the Javascript element so I can pull my data from the subscriber's version of the page?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use cookies and session, post datas, etc. consider the [cURL library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You can find a lot of examples on Internet.